# ArangoDB Thread Parameter

Tags: arangodb

In arangodb, any guidance on setting the threads parameter? I have a VM with four processors and would like to know what is the best settings for this parameter. It's currently set at four.

Comment: Did the answer fullfill your needs? If not, whats missing? If, can you mark it accepted?

Answer (score 1):

The number of server threads should equal then number of physical cores of your host.So if your Processors have 4 cores each (or 2 cores with 2 threads), 16 would be a good value. If you allow your VM to use 4 cores of these 16, use 4 server threads.

Scheduler threads usually are configured to be at least 2.